# link not turning to yellow when it is active

Tags: html, css

i wrote a simple html code with `<a>` tag. the link should turn to yellow when it is active. you can see my css code below for this. **I know that `a:link:hover` should come first then `a:link:active`, but i want to know why i don't get the yellow color when i write `a:link:active` first and then `a:link:hover`**

```css
a:link:active{
    color:rgb(238, 255, 0);
}
a:link:hover{
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<a style="font-size: 40px;" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A link is `active` while it is being clicked on.

A link is `hover`ed while the mouse is pointing to it.

You can't click on it without pointing the mouse at it.

Thus any time it is `active` is is *also* being `hover`ed (i.e. `active` **cannot** apply unless `hover` also applies).

The [cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascade-sort) says that if two rules, setting the same property have the same origin (both your rules are Author rules) and specificity (both have one type selector and two pseudo-class selectors) then *the last one overwrites the earlier ones*.

Answer (score 1):

`a:link:hover` [overwrites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade) `a:link:active` because it comes after it.

You can overcome this behavior by adding `!important` after each tag.
However, this is not recommended and should be used only when there is no other choice and you cannot use [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

```css
a:link:active {
  color: rgb(238, 255, 0) !important;
}

a:link:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a style="font-size: 40px;" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must write in CSS :hover before than :active to avoid overwrite styles.